# Google Colaboratory:read data from google driver

Tags: google-colaboratory

I  just want  to  read  `a.txt`  from  my  google  driver , when I use the  `!cat` command, I can see the output message of `a.txt`, but when I use the `pd.read_table ()` command , an error occurs because: `FileNotFoundError`.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: the error detail is in the image above,anyone warm-hearted to help me？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape a space with a backslash `\` in a string. If you do it, you're effectively adding a backslash to your string, which leads to an invalid path.

So rewrite:

```
prior=pd.read_table('/content/gdrive/My Drive/test/a.txt')
```